# prometheus-to-sd:v0.10.0-gke.0 fails after gke v1.16.9-gke.6 upgrade

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

```
[main.go:123] Failed to get GCE config: error while getting instance (node) name: metadata: GCE metadata "instance/name" not defined
```

curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/name -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google... fail

v0.8.0 works

Cluster settings:

- Security > GKE Metadata Server: Enabled
- Metadata > GCE instance metadata : disable-legacy-endpoints: true

Comment: Could you please describe in more details the issue? From where in the log you have posted?

Comment: I think this is from `resource.type="k8s_container" AND resource.labels.container_name="prometheus-to-sd-exporter"`

Comment: I have same problem on GKE v1.16.9-gke.6. GKE managed deployment kube-system/event-exporter - container prometheus-to-sd-exporter (v0.10.0-gke.0) is crash looping with this error. My cluster specific settings: Private cluster 
Enabled, GKE Metadata Server Enabled, disable-legacy-endpoints: true, Intranode visibility Enabled, Workload Identity Enabled.

Comment: I see following fields in metadata server (from another container):

`# curl -i -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/text
Metadata-Flavor: Google
Server: GKE Metadata Server
Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2020 08:21:58 GMT
Content-Length: 47

attributes/
hostname
id
service-accounts/
zone`

Comment: Found relevant issues at GitHub: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/issues/353 and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/issues/357

Comment: I've updated to GKE 1.16.13 and it's still happenning,  some people in the above github issue sayed that the error was fixed in this update. Has anyone solved it?